# getting logged out of application immediately after logging in using war on Weblogic Server

Tags: grails, weblogic

We have a Grails based application, we have developed the war file and when we deploy it in the weblogic server environment, the user after logging in immediately gets logged out, and the login screen is displayed again.

It does show the logged in screen for a fraction of a second but then logs out. Some how the session is not getting set?

The application runs fine on IDE
We havent done any changes to default configuration in Weblogic (i.e Weblogic.xml)

Comment: Anything interesting in log files?

Comment: since it isnt failing on error, there is no special entry in logs..

Comment: Ya, but there is something strange happening which is not normal. Try to find out at what line of code its happening.

Comment: Yes basically its happening only in Weblogic 10.3.4 and Linux 64 Bit. Which logs should I check?

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the server log at $DOMAIN_HOME/servers//logs/.log ? If your login module is well coded, there should be an exception in this log somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is finally fixed..
Weblogic  forwards to index.gsp by default and we added a mapping to forward it to our applications specific login page instead of lindex.gsp and now its working perfectly fine.
Thanks all for the inputs..